# Show PayPal Button through MECL without fetching a device token first?

Tags: android, paypal

I'd like to show a "Pay now via PayPal"-Button in Activity A in my app, which directs the user to Activity B (which handles the actual payment) when clicked.

The issue I'm facing is that I need to initialize the PayPal-Library twice: The first time to get the button, and the second time to send the payment information to the webservice. The initialization takes time, as the app needs to communicate with PayPal's servers. Is there any way to show the Pay Now-button without "properly" initializing the library first (I don't need the device reference token in Activity A, only in Activity B). I can't simply store a static "Pay Now"-Button-Image in my /drawable/-folder, as this is not allowed by PayPal...the button has to come from the library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by initializing the library once and then doing multiple things with the same instance (showing the "Pay Now"-button, redirecting the user to PayPal, etc.). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11341674/241189) question/answer.